# Can we declare class members within main function. why? why not?

Tags: c++, class, program-entry-point

I am a newbie so please explain accordingly -- help is greatly appreciated.

Normally we do:

```
    Class A
    {
        int a;
        ...
    }
```

Is this correct?

```
    Class A
    {
        ...
    }

    int main()
    {
        int A::a;   //declaring class member within main
    }
```

Comment: Why would you even want to do the second one?

Comment: No, you can't add extra members to a class outside of the class definition.

Comment: Class members are declared inside the class. Period. Is this really too hard to test for yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't have separate definitions of class members inside a function.

You can define a class inside a function, a **local class**, but everything must then be defined inside that class definition.

Note that C++ is a case-sensitive language. The word `Class` is not a C++ keyword. The word `class` is.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is incorrect. I don't know what you are trying to do.

If you have a static class member, you would need to define it outside the class. 
You could define the entire class within the main function but it would have little use.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared within the scope of a function are **local** to that function.  Member fields are variables that have scope within the class.  So no, you cannot declare member fields within a function.